# Numpy arrays of shape (n,) vs. (n,1) - why does this feature exist? (and unexpected addition)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the difference between numpy arrays with shapes of form `(n,)` and `(n,1)`, where `n` is some number (like 150)?

For example, `x_dat = np.random.normal(size=150)` returns an array of shape `(150,)`, whereas `a = np.matmul(np.ones((150,150)),np.ones((150,1)))` returns an array of shape `(150,1)`. When I do `np.shape(x_dat + a)`, I get `(150,150)` (whereas I really want elementwise subtraction of these two arrays, so I want an array with shape `(150,1)` as output).

I have found answers on Overflow explaining how to interconvert, but my question is about understanding (i) why this distinction exists in numpy, and (ii) what is going on such that when I add two arrays of these varying forms, I get a square matrix output as above?

Comment: (n,): This is a one-dimensional array or a vector. It has a single axis and can be thought of as a flat array. It represents a sequence of numbers.

(n,1): This is a two-dimensional array with one column. It has two axes (rows and columns) and can be thought of as a column vector or a matrix with one column. It represents a collection of n values arranged in a single column.

Comment: So why does numpy make this distinction? There are probably multiple, but I feel like the most important is broadcasting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html
This is also the mechanic that explains your (ii) point! I'd definitely recommend reading up on it if you're new to numpy.

Comment: Those are different shapes. (n,) is 1d, (n,1) is 2d (n,1,1) 3d etc.  Ever array has a `shape`.  That's a fundamental property, not just a feature.